# Ensembles 2 CloudKit

Tags: ensembles

I currently use Ensembles 1 in my app to synchronise between core data and iCloud, and I am looking to upgrade to Ensembles 2 to make use of CloudKit and the push notifications it provides.

My questions is, does Ensembles 2 handle many to many relationships between core data entities, as my app currently uses a number of these relationships

kind regards

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Ensembles does not map the Core Data model directly to the CloudKit model, it just stores transaction log files of all changes in CloudKit. This means it works just like any other cloud storage from the perspective of Ensembles.

It also means you can’t use the CloudKit data that Ensembles creates for a web service, because you have no direct access to the current stored values — data is stored as a series of changes. If you want to use CloudKit for a web service, better to implement your own sync. It's a lot more work, but gives you more control over the data.